# Angular url HTTP request

Tags: angular, http, httprequest

I have a issue with HTTP request. I am preparing backend URL in service. In console.log is url correct ("http://192.168.11.94/api/loginApi/login.php"), but after call backend, URL is incorrect ("http://192.168.11.94/192.168.11.94/api/loginApi/login.php").

Asi you can cee, in URL is IP adress twice. I don't know why. In development (localhost) everything running corectly.

I tried write url to request directly, but it not works.
Setting API url:

```
localStorage.setItem("api", "192.168.11.94/api/");
```

Request:

```
  apiUrl = localStorage.getItem("api");

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  login(username:string, password:string) {
    console.log(this.apiUrl);
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.apiUrl + 'loginApi/login.php', {username, password});  
    }
```

In this case, consolelog() show: 192.168.11.94/api/, but call trying this URL: http://192.168.11.94/192.168.11.94/api/loginApi/login.php

I found, deleting this.apiUrl from code works for ng build --prod, but not works in develoment. :/

Thank you for help! :)

Comment: can you share your code. How you are calling the api  and where are your crating the url?

Comment: apiUrl = localStorage.getItem("api");                                   
login(username:string, password:string) {
    console.log(this.apiUrl);
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.apiUrl + 'loginApi/login.php', {username, password});  
    }

Comment: update your question with code and show where and how you are storing value in local storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you not need to add the url in the post if its a same address.
just like:

```
login(username:string, password:string) {
    console.log(this.apiUrl);
    return this.httpClient.post<any>('/api/loginApi/login.php', {username, password});  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by adding http:// to the definition of URL.

```
localStorage.setItem("api", "http://192.168.11.94/api/");
```